# How to connect two Apple devices to separate Wi-Fi network with same Apple ID?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ios

I have dual band Wi-Fi network at my home with different SSIDs. I want to keep my Mac on 5GHz network for bandwidth, whereas keeping my iPhone on 2.4GHz for more coverage.

No matter how many times I rearrange the order of my Wi-Fi Networks preferences, my Mac always tend to connect to same SSID as my iPhone. I tried following things without success:

1. If I delete a Network from Mac, it gets deleted from iPhone.
2. If I add the network back to iPhone, it gets added to Mac.
3. If I add a Network to Mac, it gets added to iPhone.

Is there a way to allow difference Apple devices registered to the same Apple-Id, to connect to different Wi-Fi networks at same location?

Comment: See here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112729/selectively-disable-icloud-keychain-syncing-for-wifi-passwords

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you for the pointer the second answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the lead from @Appleoddity, this answer solved the problem https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191277